# Mongrel clusters are running parallel on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I have setup my rails application on windows With Mongrel application server and Apache Web server .

I have defined the 10 cluster for mongrel to handle the request properly .
When I make any request that has heavy db operation or that require time to execute , then all my mongrel cluster are busy and displaying same log .

Same mongrel cluster setting are working fine on Linux server .

Can you please get me out of this bottleneck .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was stuck into the log issue .

So I have set different log file for each cluster and things are working fine .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the native database access library is locking something or the database itself is configured in the such a way that only exclusive access to the relevant tables is allowed.  (Most likely the former by the sound of it, assuming it's the exact same database that is being accessed from the Linux-served version of your app too.)

As such, the answer to your question is probably rooted in the particular database provider you are using.  Which is it... sqlite, Postgres, MySQL, MS SQL Server?

Comment: Database is MySQL. And I think issue was not due to database . I was stuck in between the log files, so I have set different for each cluster and things are working fine . Thanks for your respond .